# Regex - Find text after @ and before specific chars

Tags: python, regex

I have this code:

```
replies = re.findall(r'@([^\\s]+)', string_content_here)
```

What I am trying to do is to find all usernames after @ sign. I only want to find @ strings before space, comma, exclamation mark and question mark.

Examples:

```
@Spindel <--- Should return Spindel
@Spindel, <--- Should return Spindel
@Spindel! <--- Should return Spindel
@Spindel? <--- Should return Spindel
@gmail.com <--- I don't want this at all
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
r'@([\w]+)(?:$|[ ,!?])'
```

The `?:` is there to make the second group "non-capturing", so you get only the names you want in the results.

Comment: How can I add newline as a "non-capturing" in the second group?

Comment: Try putting `\n` inside the `[]` brackets.  Not tested though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this, its not perfect but should do the trick

```
replies = re.findall("@(\\w+)[ ,!?]", string_content_here)
```